# Clang/LLVM 7 and 8 on Windows initialize inline static data member multiple times (with both link.exe and lld-link.exe)

Tags: c++, clang, c++17, llvm-clang

Clang/LLVM 7 and 8 on Windows initialize an inline static data member **once per TU**. As far as I understand C++17 this is not correct.

Although an inline variable may be defined in multiple TUs the compiler and/or linker must ensure that it exists only once in a program and hence is **initialized exactly once**.

The following little program shows what happens with Clang/LLVM (tested in Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 RC with LLVM Compiler Toolchain extension):

// header.h

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
  A()      { std::cout << "ctor " << this << std::endl; }
  ~A()     { std::cout << "dtor " << this << std::endl; }
  void f() { std::cout << "f " << this << std::endl;  }
};

struct S
{
  inline static A a; // C++17 inline variable, thus also a definition 
};
```

// TU1.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
  S::a.f();
}
```

// TU2.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
```

// TU3.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
```

// TU4.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
```

This program prints:

```
ctor 010D4020
ctor 010D4020
ctor 010D4020
ctor 010D4020
f 010D4020
dtor 010D4020
dtor 010D4020
dtor 010D4020
dtor 010D4020
```

That's **four** initializations for the one and only object of A (in fact one per TU) instead of **exactly one** (as C++17 demands).

The program should print:

```
ctor 010D4020
f 010D4020
dtor 010D4020
```

This is what MSVC does, by the way.

This is a bug in clang/LLVM, right?

Comment: What compile options are you using for Clang?

Comment: What's the difference from [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50946270/5376789) you previously asked?

Comment: @xskxzr The other question refers to lld-link.exe, this one to link.exe.

Comment: @SergeBallesta -Xclang -std=c++17 -Xclang -flto -Xclang -O3

Comment: Does it depend on the optimization options? And what if you remove `-flto` and what is the meaning of `-Xclang`? As you use `-std=c++17`, I really think that this is a Clang problem but I think that you need to only use relevant option in order to fill a bug report.

Comment: Removing both -flto and -O3 does not change anything. So it does not depend on these two options. -Xclang is necessary for clang's cl.exe (I'm using Visual Studio 2017) because these options must be passed directly to clang. Otherwise they are unused (in case of -O3) or confuse link.exe (in case of -flto).

Comment: I can't reproduce with Clang 7.0.1 (x86_64-w64-windows-gnu) that comes with MSYS2, but I'm using `clang++` rather than `clang-cl`, as I don't have a VS installed.

Comment: Yes, I think it's very specific only to clang-cl. For example, there is no error on Wandbox the last time I tested it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The primary feature of the `inline` keyword is that it amends the ODR rule in two ways:

1. Multiple definitions (with some restrictions) are [allowed](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#4)
2. The resulting objects are "folded" into a [single instance](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.inline#6):

   > An inline function or variable with external linkage shall have the same address in all translation units.

The only addition in C++17 is that it also [allows](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.static.data#2) a `static` data member declaration to be a definition. That's it.

A `static` data member still has the same *linkage* ([*external*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.link#4) in your case), [storage duration](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.stc.static#1) and [lifetime](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#1.1), and for all practical purposes works just like a globally defined variable.
See [[class.static.data]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mem#class.static.data-6):

> Static data members are initialized and destroyed exactly like non-local variables

That means essentially that it should work the same as this:

```
struct A
{
  A()      { std::cout << "ctor "; }
  ~A()     { std::cout << "dtor "; }
};

A a; // in one of the TU's

extern A a; // in all other TU's
```

**Conclusion:**

It's a bug in Clang. The `static` `S::a` must be initialized and destroyed once.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected. I'll file a bug report on llvm.org.

Comment: Well, I reported this as a bug in June 2018 for 6.0.0. But even in the brand new 8.0.0 it is still there. Does anyone know why this is not fixed?

Comment: Is the bug still present in Clang 13? I think so.

Answer (score 1):

[This bug is fixed](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37903) in the current snapshot build based on SVN r361807.